# Compare the following ideals: $(I+J)/I$ and $J/(I\cap J)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the question says I have to compare the following ideals.
I am not quite sure what "comparison" in this case would mean and I really have no idea how to do that.

I have defined $(I+J)/I=\{(i+j)+I| i \in I, j\in J\}$ and as far as I have read this is the smallest ideal containing I and J.
I have absolutely no clue how to define $J/(I\cap J)$ since I don't know how to define the intersection.

I would be very thanful for some insight regarding comparing them with each other.

EDIT: The ideals are in a commutative unitary ring.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about it, they are in a commutative ring with neutral element, I edited it.

Comment: So take $R=\Bbb Z$ and $I=m\Bbb Z$ and $J=n\Bbb Z$. What do you get?

Comment: are they the same?

Comment: $(I+J)/I$ is not an ideal but a quotient of two groups, being ideals they are $R$-modules, so the quotient is again a $R$-module. The problem is to understand the natural map $J\to (I+J)/I$. Is it an homomorphism? Is it compatible with the $R$-module operations? What is its image? What is its kernel?

Comment: I don't really know, it's the first time we are doing ideals so it's all pretty abstract to me.

Comment: See Theorem B at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).